# How to query "has no linked records in this table"

Tags: postgresql

I have two simple tables: `one` with primary key `id`, and `two` with primary key `id` and a foreign key `oneId`.

I want to get all rows from `one` with no references in `two.oneId`.

I could do

- `SELECT ... FROM one LEFT JOIN two ON two.oneId = one.id WHERE two.id IS NULL`
- `SELECT ... FROM one WHERE NOT exists(SELECT 1 FROM two WHERE oneId = one.id)`
- `SELECT ... FROM one WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT oneId FROM two)`
- probably other options exist

Which option is better, and why?

Comment: I would vote for outer join. but why not `explain analyze`?..

Comment: Check the execution plans (generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second choice is the best – it will be translated to an antijoin.

Number one looks pretty good too, it might have the same execution plan.